# res.download not working in my case when i pass variable from window.location.href

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to download my file that has been generated with res.download.

I'm passing variable filename and path like this :

```js
 window.location.href = "/transaction/api/downloadfile?filename="+res.filename;
                  }, 3000);
```

And here is my code to download file in routes.

```js
router.get("/api/downloadfile", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.filename);
    res.download(req.query.filename); 

    res.render("pages/Admin/PO/createpo");
});
```

Here is req.query.filename : **D:\stock-management-project(1)\stock-management-project\z1z97bvhbh9.pdf**

Please help me for this issue :)

Thank you everyone.